# Determine disabled state element when child of disabled fieldset

Tags: javascript, dom

If an input is disabled because it is a child of a disabled fieldset, IE (even 11) doesn't seem to have any way of determining that it's disabled.  Is there some way to determine that without searching the tree?

Obviously, I could use jQuery to find the closest fieldset and check to see if that's disabled if it exists, but that seems hacky, not to mention potentially expensive.  I *could* look at the currentStyle to determine if it's greyed out - but that's even more hacky.  Am I missing something?

```
<fieldset disabled>
  <input id="fieldset_child" type="text" value="Inherit Disabled" />
</fieldset>

<script>
  // IE 9-11 returns zero instead of one like Firefox and Chrome do
  console.log(document.querySelectorAll('#fieldset_child:disabled').length);

  // this return false in all browsers 
  console.log(document.getElementById('fieldset_child').disabled);
</script>
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/cmcnulty/ySWH2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it turns out that Internet Explorer exposes a property called isDisabled (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533902%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which is how it tracks things that inherit their disabledness.  Using that, in combination with testing the nodeName to only check the various form elements, you can determine with good performance whether something is disabled.  Untested in IE6-7.

Answer (score 1):

The "inheriting" `input` is not truly disabled in IE, it just *appears* disabled, you can **still type into it**. A truly foolproof method to disable the child inputs when disabling the `fieldset` is to apply `disabled` attribute to individual inputs. Then they will be truly disabled and you will be able to find them via `document.querySelectorAll`

Comment: That's an interesting observation, however, for the purposes of form submission, the input actually *is* disabled - it is not submitted in the form submit: http://jsfiddle.net/ySWH2/7/  Also, select fields can't be opened - further highlighting their "disabledness"

Comment: Makes sense. But since they're not "completely" disabled they cannot be found via `:disabled` selector. Applying `disabled` to the inputs themselves makes them findable. As it is in your current HTML sample - cant you use `document.querySelectorAll('fieldset[disabled] #fieldset_child')` selector instead? http://jsfiddle.net/ySWH2/8/